# how to grep or egrep words that appear twice in a row?

Tags: bash, grep, row, repeat, cpu-word

Hi there I am wanting to know how to `grep` lines that have a word repeated twice in a row. A space between the two words obviously has to be accounted for and it has to be case sensitive which I believe `grep` naturally is.

I do not just want an answer rather I want to know how to do it and understand it. So anyone that responds could you also please explain what the line is saying or what the pattern is doing. I have a basic to intermediate grasp on `grep` and `bash` however still learning all the intricacies of `grep` and the correlating syntax. Any and all help would be much appreciated.

This is as close as I have not gotten lol although I am also unsure of what exactly I am doing here...

```
grep '.*\|.*\| '
```

Thanks all!!
Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

You would use `grep -E '(\<[^[:blank:]]+\>).*\1'`

The `\<` and `\>` represent word boundaries. Together with the sequence of non-blank characters, that forms a single word. Then the `\1` recalls that first set of capturing parentheses.

Comment: Unfortunately, many tools use slightly different flavours of regular expressions. The regexes for GNU tools (grep, awk, etc) can be found at https://www.gnu.org/software/gnulib/manual/html_node/Regular-expression-syntaxes.html#Regular-expression-syntaxes

Answer (score 1):

\1 matches every string that was matched by the first string that was matched. That is not the same as matching the same pattern that was matched by the first string. So the first capture matched on a word boundary is no longer relevant, even though the \b is inside the capture parentheses.

If you want the second instance to be on a word boundary too then you have to say so.

Also by using regular expressions, we can say we want all small a-z and big A-Z words. Also by using the + we say that the preceding characters matches atleast 1 or more times.

```
egrep "(\b[a-zA-Z]+) \1\b" file.txt
```

This will show you all the words that are used twice.

```
grep -E "(\b[a-zA-Z]+) \1\b" file.txt
```

This command will also work if you rather want to use grep. grep -E means it uses extended regular expressions. So it's the same as egrep.